# Dynamics AX - Send HTML file as email

Tags: axapta

I'm very new to Dynamics AX. Currently I use AX 4.0. I have written a code to send plain text as email, now that I need to send an email as HTML format. I have an HTML file with me which has to be set as body of the Email class while sending. I'm not finding appropriate way to do it? Could anybody guide me the basic steps I need to follow so that I can take over from there?

I need to do this only in AX 4.0.

Thanks in Advance

~achu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of sending email from AX. 
If you use .net class as suggested here :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952736
Then you can set the mailmessage as html as follows :

```
 mailMessage.set_IsBodyHtml(true);
```

If you use other methods, each has its own way of setting html.
You may want to look at these blogs :
http://sumitsaxfactor.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/email-techniques-in-ax-4-0/
http://waikeatng.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/sending-emails-from-dynamics-ax.html